# SQL Server Installation issue

Tags: sql

i have installed ms sql server 2005 properly but there isnt option to open sql management studio..
in start--> all program --> sql server 2005. shows only configuration tools and no option like sql server management studio so what is the problem and how to start sql mangnt studio???

please help me out in this
waiting for positive replies.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

So you installed the server, but sql server management studio is a seperate piece of software, you should install it too.

[Download](https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?pf=true&id=8961) it here in case you have not

Comment: Thank you so much for help me out in this...
thanks again

Comment: @Darshan Bhatt: If it helped you can accept by clicking the checkmark on the left to mark the question as solved. If you found a better solution you can write your own answer and accept your own.